# Почему не срабатывает атрибут f:ajax onerror JSF MyFaces 2.2.5 + Primefaces 5?

Tags: jsf, javascript, java, ajax

На версии MyFaces 2.0 + Primefaces 3.5 все нормально.
Есть, к примеру, такой код:

```
<h:commandButton value="Display Text" action="#{indexBean.action}"> 
    <f:ajax execute="@this input" render="output" onevent="handleEvent" onerror="handleError"/>            
</h:commandButton>
```

На стороне сервера при определенном действии устанавливаем ответу код ошибки 500, при котором Ajax engine должен перехватить ответ и отдать его обработчику ошибок, но данного не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces 5 имеет встроенный AjaxExceptionHandler, о и обрабатывает все ошибки не задействую стандартный механизм.